# angularjs find properties of div in directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

new to angular, new to stackoverflow. been trying to solve this for days. here is my problem:

I want to center a group of boxes.

Is there a way to get access to properties of div's (with id or class names) and manipulate them in a directive?

in my html I am creating divs with ng-repeat, the divs are the boxes that are displayed. I have a directive that I, for now, am trying to use to find and manipulate properties of the div's/directives in the html, however I can't seem to do this.

I have googled a lot and have found similar issues but nothing that seems to work in my code.

here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3m87R/

```
app.directive('someBoxes', function()
{
    return function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
        element.css('border', '1px solid white');
        //element.css('width', '200px');

        var body = angular.element(document).find('.bookitem');
        console.log(body[0].offsetWidth);

        if(scope.$last)
        {
            //console.log("element name is: " + element.attr("class"));
            //console.log("element is: " + element);
            //console.log($(".bookitem").children("div").attr("class"));
            //console.log($('.container').children('div').attr('class'));
        }
    };
});
```

Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: Did you take a look on transclude ? I think it will be better to use ng-repeat in a transclude inside of your custom tag

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because ng-repeat changes the DOM, the children elements are not available 
during directive compilation.
so a $watch is needed on child elements.

This notifies the directive that child elements are added and then perform operation on them.

The $watch must skip the nodeType which is "comment:(type 8)"

> here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3m87R/3/

The part in link:

```
 link: function ($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                    $scope.$watch(element.children(),function(){
                    var children = element.children();
                    for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
                        if(children[i].nodeType !== 8){
                            angular.element(children[i]).css('background', 'orange');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the effort, I tried this in my code but it doesn't seem to work, also I don't understand the 'not equal to 8' part. Also this doesn't get the properties of the new elements. But thank you for your effort.

Comment: just provide fiddle of your use case..

well angularjs adds node type8 while performing ng-repeat, so it should be skipped, for more check out : http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp

Comment: it has the html that is calling the directive and the directive.  The directive is inside a controller.js file the html is in a home.html file that gets loaded into the index.html file via the app.js everything works fine except I don't know how to retrieve in the directive, the properties of the div that calls the directive (or the directive in the html file whatever you term it).  I will try your solution again.

Answer (score 0):

You are close! I was able to get the directive working in one of my test fiddles. Take a look.

```
$(element).css('border', '1px solid red');
$(element).css('text-align', 'center');
```

See this fiddle where I have a sample of your directive.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/311chaos/vUUf4/4/)

Comment: Hey is there a way to not hardcode the height in the html that you have there? I am trying to find the width (or any other properties) of the element in the directive dynamically I guess. So imagine there being 3 boxes created, they appear in a row but they are left justified.  I want the directive to FIND their widths, then do the centering etc itself then apply that to the elements. hope this is clear, thanks for the effort.